# create Xero invoice using python request raise "No data has been processed for this endpoint. This endpoint is expecting Invoice data to be specifed"

Tags: python, python-requests, xero-api

I am trying to create an Invoice in Xero accounting using one of the Xero provided rest api, i used a Python requests library to access the certain Invoice rest api but unable to create an invoice. It raise following error

`{'ErrorNumber': 17, 'Type': 'NoDataProcessedException', 'Message': 'No data has been processed for this endpoint. This endpoint is expecting Invoice data to be specifed in the request body.'}`

Here is my my python code,

```
def XeroRequests():
    new_tokens = XeroRefreshToken('*****************************')
    xero_tenant_id = XeroTenants(new_tokens[0])
   
    get_url = 'https://api.xero.com/api.xro/2.0/Invoices'
    response = requests.post(get_url,
                        headers = {
                            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + new_tokens[0],
                            'Xero-tenant-id': xero_tenant_id,
                            'Accept': 'application/json'
                        },
                        data = {
                              "Type": "ACCREC",
                              "Contact": {
                                "ContactID": "eaa28f49-6028-4b6e-bb12-d8f6278073fc"
                              },
                              "Date": "\/Date(1518685950940+0000)\/",
                              "DueDate": "\/Date(1518685950940+0000)\/",
                              "DateString": "2009-05-27T00:00:00",
                              "DueDateString": "2009-06-06T00:00:00",
                              "LineAmountTypes": "Exclusive",
                              "LineItems": [
                                {
                                  "Description": "Consulting services as agreed (20% off standard rate)",
                                  "Quantity": "10",
                                  "UnitAmount": "100.00",
                                  "AccountCode": "200",
                                  "DiscountRate": "20"
                                }
                              ]
                            })
                        
    json_response = response.json()
    print("POST response ", json_response)
```

Whats wrong i did here?

Answer (score 0):

You need to give data like this as per the API [documentation](https://developer.xero.com/documentation/api/accounting/invoices)

```
data = {
        "Invoices": [{
              "Type": "ACCREC",
              "Contact": {
                "ContactID": "eaa28f49-6028-4b6e-bb12-d8f6278073fc"
              },
              "Date": "\/Date(1518685950940+0000)\/",
              "DueDate": "\/Date(1518685950940+0000)\/",
              "DateString": "2009-05-27T00:00:00",
              "DueDateString": "2009-06-06T00:00:00",
              "LineAmountTypes": "Exclusive",
              "LineItems": [
                {
                  "Description": "Consulting services as agreed (20% off standard rate)",
                  "Quantity": "10",
                  "UnitAmount": "100.00",
                  "AccountCode": "200",
                  "DiscountRate": "20"
                }
              ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

Comment: still getting the same error 

`{'ErrorNumber': 17, 'Type': 'NoDataProcessedException', 'Message': 'No data has been processed for this endpoint. This endpoint is expecting Invoice data to be specifed in the request body.'}`

Comment: @Md.TanvirRaihan You are missing `"CurrencyCode": "USD"` in your data can you add that and try again?

Comment: still same error.

Answer (score 0):

Try shortening your description. I just had the same error, which was odd as the exact same code was working on other invoices, then I noticed the description on one was longer than the other. I shortened it, and the error disappeared and the invoice was created.

Comment: If not length, it could be there are restricted characters... brackets etc

Answer (score 0):

If you intend to pass in the python dictionary you have, you need to add the content type header and turn the dictionary into json. Here is an example of the headers that I'm using

```py
headers = {
    'Xero-Tenant-Id': ***,
    'Authorization': ***',
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}
```

Here is how you set up the payload.

```py
payload = json.dumps({
        "Invoices": [{
              "Type": "ACCREC",
              "Contact": {
                "ContactID": "eaa28f49-6028-4b6e-bb12-d8f6278073fc"
              },
              "Date": "\/Date(1518685950940+0000)\/",
              "DueDate": "\/Date(1518685950940+0000)\/",
              "DateString": "2009-05-27T00:00:00",
              "DueDateString": "2009-06-06T00:00:00",
              "LineAmountTypes": "Exclusive",
              "LineItems": [
                {
                  "Description": "Consulting services as agreed (20% off standard rate)",
                  "Quantity": "10",
                  "UnitAmount": "100.00",
                  "AccountCode": "200",
                  "DiscountRate": "20"
                }
              ]
            }
        ]
})
```

Basically xero is expecting a specific format that it's not getting.